# Importing CSV file into Access using C# but data is out of order

Tags: c#, sql, csv, ms-access, crystal-reports

Going a bit old school today trying to fix a bit of software that is running in a manufacturing plant importing data from a CSV file into an access database which is used to generate Crystal reports!

The original CSV file is in RANK (1,2,3, etc) order but when its imported using the following code it often arrives in the Access database out of order.

```
using (OleDbCommand accComm2 = new OleDbCommand(String.Format("SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT vCSV.* INTO {0} FROM [Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;DATABASE={1}].[{2}] as vCSV ORDER BY vCSV.RANK", dbtable, Path.GetDirectoryName(fname), Path.GetFileName(fname)), accConn, accTran))
                        {
                            accComm2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
```

This causes issues further down the line as the quirky crystal report manufacturing summarys that are created require the data to be in rank order.

Because the Crystal report is grouped into batches, you cant do the sorting on the crystal report end.

Does anyone have any ideas why the above wouldnt be working? Weve even tried importing it to a temporary table and then to the live table, effectively doing the sort command twice but it still sometimes fails!

Comment: Is there are particular reason you can't just resort the data in the report?  Sort order of records in a database shouldn't matter because you can control the sort order when selecting data from the database.

Comment: Because the Crystal report is grouped into batches, you cant do the sorting on the crystal report end. The batches consist of multiple records whioch are grouped together due to being the same product. The batches need to be displayed in rank order

Comment: can you create a query and sort it there and use the query as the data source for your report

Comment: Remove any sorting of the CSV file. It the ` {0} ` table you have sort using a query - which you then use as source for the report. That said, Access reports _must_ be sorted in the report itself and nowhere else; don't know if that is the same for Crystal Reports.

Answer (score 0):

You should sort in a subquery before inserting. Sorting while inserting has no effect in Access, besides the preview you can get while inserting.

```
SELECT * INTO {0} FROM (SELECT TOP 100 * [Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;DATABASE={1}].[{2}]  ORDER BY RANK) as vCSV
```

Note that, strictly speaking, the resulting table has no index thus is a heap and has no defined sort order (there is no first/second/nth record, any ordering is equally valid). Practically, this will likely work, though.

Comment: _Sorting while inserting has no effect in Access_ ... true, but isn't that what your code attempts to do?

Comment: It sorts first, then inserts, since it executes the subquery first, which has worked for me in the past. Strangely, however, for me sorting while inserting works with my current build, so I can't verify the issue and fix.

Comment: That's the trap. It may work - until some day when it doesn't for no apparent reason.